# How to change parameter in serializer through view in django rest api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

ok here is a deal

serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from happytourist.models import PointsInterestData


class PointsInterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer, serializers.Serializer):
  distance = serializers.SerializerMethodField(default=None)

def get_distance(self, obj):
    distance_view = self.context.get('distance')
    return distance_view

class Meta:
    model = PointsInterestData
    fields = ('name', 'latitude', 'longtitude', 'distance')
    read_only_fields = fields
```

my view:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import PointsInterestSerializer
from happytourist.models import PointsInterestData


class PointsInterestList(generics.ListCreateAPIView, generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = PointsInterestSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = PointsInterestData.objects.all()
    return queryset

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_latitude = request.POST.get('latitude')
    user_longtitude = request.POST.get('longtitude')
    radius = request.POST.get('radius')
    usergeodata = {'user_latitude': user_latitude, 'user_longtitude': user_longtitude, 'radius': radius}
    return usergeodata

def get_coordinates(self):
    latitude = PointsInterestData.objects.model.latitude
    longtitude = PointsInterestData.objects.model.longtitude
    geodata = {"latitude": latitude, "longtitude": longtitude}
    return geodata

def distancecalc(self, request):
    user_latitude = self.post(request=self.request)['user_latitude']
    user_longtitude = self.post(request=self.request)['user_longtitude']

    latitude = self.get_coordinates()['latitude']
    longtitude = self.get_coordinates()['latitude']

    x = longtitude - user_longtitude
    y = latitude - user_latitude
    distance = int((x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** (1 / 2))
    return distance

def get_serializer_context(self):
    distance_result = PointsInterestList.distancecalc(self, request=self.request)
    context = super(PointsInterestList, self).get_serializer_context()
    context.update({'distance': distance_result})
    return context
```

What I need to do is to get post latitude, and longtitude, get latitude and longtitude from model, calculate the distance between them. My problem is to transform the distance into new value. In the view I have post where i post these two values. In get coordinates i get two values from model. In distancecalc I want to calculate.

Comment: why not `distance_result = self.distancecalc(self.request)`?

Comment: i have got these error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'NoneType'